# Interpolation inequality for Holder continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, holder-spaces, interpolation-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open connected set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $C^1$ boundary and let $0<\alpha<1$. Then there exists a real number $\sigma_0>0$ and a dimensional constant $C>0$ such that $$||Du||_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\leq \sigma^\alpha [|Du|]_{\alpha,\Omega}+\frac{C}{\sigma}||u||_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$$ and $$[u]_{\alpha,\Omega}\leq \sigma[|Du|]_{\alpha,\Omega}+\frac{C}{\sigma^\alpha}||u||_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$$ hold for all $0<\sigma<\sigma_0$ and for all $u\in C^{1,\alpha}(\bar\Omega)$. Here $||u||_{C^{1,\alpha}}=||u||_{L^\infty(\Omega)}+||Du||_{L^\infty(\Omega)}+[|Du|]_{\alpha}$ and $[u]_\alpha=\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}$.

N.B. I have proved the above results for balls and then for domain with $C^2$ boundary. I cant proceed for $C^1$ boundary domain. Any help will be great.

Comment: It might help if you showed how you dealt with $C^2$ boundaries.

Comment: $C^2$ boundary have the interior ball property and i have the results for balls.

Comment: @mudok May I know how do you use interior ball property to get the desired result for $C^2$ domains? I understand the inequality holds for balls, but I am not sure how to connect them together. Ideally I want to show for each $x$ in the domain, there exists a ball contained in $\Omega$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\Omega$ is bounded, its closure its compact. Also since $u\in
C^{1,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$, you have that $Du$ is continuous. Hence
there exists $x_{0}\in\overline{\Omega}$ such that
$$
|Du(x_{0})|=\max_{x\in\overline{\Omega}}|Du(x)|.
$$
In particular, $u$ is differentiable $x_{0}$. Thus,
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}(x_{0})=Du(x_{0})\cdot\nu,
$$
where $\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}$ is a directional derivative in an
admissible direction $\nu\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, with $|\nu|=1$. Now since
$\partial\Omega$ is of class $C^{1}$, there is a cone $C$ such that every
point $x\in\overline{\Omega}$ is the vertex of a cone $C_{x}$ congruent to $C$
and contained in $\Omega$. Hence, if you consider the cone $C_{x_{0}}$, you
can find $n$ linearly independent directions $\nu_{1},\ldots,\nu_{n}$ such
that the segments $x_{0}+t\nu_{i}$, $t\in\lbrack0,h]$ are contained in the
cone $C_{x_{0}}$, where $h>0$. If you consider the system of $n$ equations
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu_{i}}(x_{0})=Du(x_{0})\cdot\nu_{i},
$$
in the $n$ unknowns $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}}(x_{0})$, you have that
the determinant is different from zero since the vectors are linearly
independent. Hence, you can write
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}}(x_{0})=\sum_{j=1}^{n}c_{i,j}\frac{\partial
u}{\partial\nu_{j}}(x_{0}),
$$
where the numbers $c_{i,j}$ depent only on the directions $\nu_{1},\ldots
,\nu_{n}$.

Along each segment $S_{i}=\{x_{0}+t\nu_{i}$, $t\in\lbrack0,h]\}$ you can apply
your inequality for $n=1$ to the function $g_{i}(t):=u(x_{0}+t\nu_{i})$,
$t\in\lbrack0,h]$.

Now you have to prove that the coefficients $c_{i,j}$ depend only on $\Omega$.
I have to think about this, but if you rotate the cone, your new directions
are $R\nu_{1},\ldots,R\nu_{n}$, where $R$ is your rotation, so the determinant
should not change.

Comment: Very nice argument. What you essentially use is the interior cone property for $C^1$ domain. Which escaped my mind. I also think your $c_{i,j}$ dependence only on domain since it's come from the linear independent direction vectors depending on domain. Am I correct?

Comment: yes, you are correct

Comment: one question : you say " a cone Cx congruent to C and contained in Ω" why congruent?

Comment: up to a translation and a rotation. And I should have said contained in the closure of $\Omega$. You will need to rotate the cone.

Comment: $C^1$ boundary imply uniform cone property or only cone property?

Comment: Different books have a different definition. In https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898719826 uniform cone property is equivalent to uniformly Lipschitz (so OK for bounded C^1). In the paper of Fraenkel https://academic.oup.com/plms/article-abstract/s3-39/3/385/1496339 C^1 boundary have the strong cone property. All these definitions use rigid motions (that is, congruent cones).

Comment: @Gio67 May I know why the cone property of the boundary (for all $x\in\partial\Omega$) implies the cone property also holds for the domain (for all $x\in \bar{\Omega}$)?

Comment: I did not say that. I am not sure that's even true. I only used the fact that a bounded domain of class $C^1$ has the strong cone property. It's Theorem 4.3 (C) in the paper of Fraenkel.